# ComboBox fill from index 0

Tags: java, netbeans, combobox

I have a `ComboBox` that get its items from my database when the program starts.
Here is the code

```
private void fillComboBox(){
    try{
        String query = "SELECT * FROM `Books`";
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()){
            String name = rs.getString("BookName");
            searchComboBox.addItem(name);
        }
    }catch(Exception ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
    }finally{
        try{
            rs.close();
            ps.close();
        }catch(Exception ex){

        }
    }
}
```

But whenever i call this method twice it add items on each other not start adding items from 0
In other words when i call `fillComboBox()` method first time it adds **item1, item2 item 3** and when i call it again it adds on the first items not create new item list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to call `removeAllItems()` at the beginning or prevent the method to be called several times...

```
// I assumed searchComboBox is JComboBox
searchComboBox.removeAllItems();
```

Comment: how i didn't think about that! thanks a lot you really helped me:D :D